# Trying to use PDO for inserting rows in mysql not working

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

To which the browser shows no errors but the data is not sent:

```
<?php

    $dsn = 'mysql:dbname=eportfolio;host=localhost';
    $user ='root';
    $pass ='exia';

    try{
    $db =new PDO($dsn,$user,$pass);
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    }catch(PDOException $e){
        echo "ERROR" .$e->getMessage() ;
    }
    if (isset($_POST['Submit'])){
    if(isset($_POST['Nom'])){ $Nom = $_POST['Nom']; }
    if(isset($_POST['Prenom'])){ $Prenom = $_POST['Prenom']; }
    if(isset($_POST['Adresse'])){ $Adresse = $_POST['Adresse']; }
    if(isset($_POST['Mail'])){ $Mail = $_POST['Mail']; }
    if(isset($_POST['Telephone'])){ $name = $_POST['Telephone']; }

    $sql ="INSERT INTO profil(Nom,Prenom,Adresse,Mail,Telephone) VALUES(:Nom,:Prenom,:Adresse,:Mail,:Telephone)";


    try{
        $query= $db->prepare($sql);
        $query->bindParam(':Nom',$Nom);
        $query->bindParam(':Prenom',$Prenom);
        $query->bindParam(':Adresse',$Adresse);
        $query->bindParam(':Mail',$Mail);
        $query->bindParam(':Telephone',$Telephone);
        try{
        $query->execute($sql);
        }catch(PDOException $e){
        echo "tnaket" .$e->getMessage() ;
    }

    }catch(PDOException $e){
        echo $sql .$e->getMessage() ;
    }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Perhaps the MySQL server is configured to have autocommit mode disabled by default?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: okay i'll check again, thanks

Comment: `$query->execute()`; it already has the query assigned here `$db->prepare($sql);`.

Comment: Got my money on the html form too. But I'll take low odds on that one.

Comment: @Fred-ii- 3:1 on undeclared?

Comment: @chris85 Sure, you're on.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

    $dsn = 'mysql:dbname=eportfolio;host=localhost';
    $user ='root';
    $pass ='exia';

    try{
    $db =new PDO($dsn,$user,$pass);
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    }catch(PDOException $e){
        echo "ERROR" .$e->getMessage() ;
    }
    if (isset($_POST['Submit'])){
    if(isset($_POST['Nom'])){ $Nom = $_POST['Nom']; }
    if(isset($_POST['Prenom'])){ $Prenom = $_POST['Prenom']; }
    if(isset($_POST['Adresse'])){ $Adresse = $_POST['Adresse']; }
    if(isset($_POST['Mail'])){ $Mail = $_POST['Mail']; }
    if(isset($_POST['Telephone'])){ $Telephone = $_POST['Telephone']; }

    $sql ="INSERT INTO profil(Nom,Prenom,Adresse,Mail,Telephone) VALUES(:Nom,:Prenom,:Adresse,:Mail,:Telephone)";


    try{
        $query= $db->prepare($sql);
        $query->bindParam(':Nom',$Nom);
        $query->bindParam(':Prenom',$Prenom);
        $query->bindParam(':Adresse',$Adresse);
        $query->bindParam(':Mail',$Mail);
        $query->bindParam(':Telephone',$Telephone);
        try{
        $query->execute($query);
        }catch(PDOException $e){
        echo "tnaket" .$e->getMessage() ;
    }

    }catch(PDOException $e){
        echo $sql .$e->getMessage() ;
    }
    }
?>
```

You were missing `$Telephone` in the variable declaration

Comment: It already has the query assigned in the `prepare`. http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php `$query->execute();`.

Comment: Umair Khan thanks for drawing my attention to it

Comment: chris85 as it turns out that php is using mysqli extention instead of php-pdo

Comment: @Bendaoudachraf Your code referenced PDO, do you mean `PDO` isn't available on your server?

Comment: chris85 it is avialable but the default php extention used is mysqli